# How to insert values from File_get_contents into Mysql via php Script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, file-get-contents

I have a problem.

I want to take the information of a website. This website includes several .csv files
So i make a loop that generates the link files of these .csv's

I take those link files and i put them into variables like that.

```
$data = ( iconv("windows-1253","UTF-8",file_get_contents($xeimerino)));
$data1 = ( iconv("windows-1253","UTF-8",file_get_contents($earino)));
```

where $xeimerino,$earino is the produced link of the .csv files.
I also have a script that processes these .csv in order to have them in a good html format to be shown via .php here is the code.

```
echo "<br />";
$z = array_filter(explode("\x0A",$data));
?><div><?PHP
echo '<table border="1">';
foreach($z as $k=>$v){

$w = explode(';',rtrim($v,";"));
echo '<tr>';
foreach( $w as $td ) {
 echo "<td>$td</td>"; 


}
echo '</tr>';
}   
echo '</table>';
```

Now i want to ask how am i supposed to insert those values taken from the .csv files and properly-beatifully shown with the second part of code into a table in mysql.

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first download the file to the server and use `LOAD DATA INFILE`. If your php and database are on the same server use the mysql keyword `local` otherwise if they are on two different servers omit the keyword `local`

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/location/of/file.csv' /* Omit 'local' if two different servers */
INTO TABLE my_table /* Set your tablename */
(column1, column2, column3) /* Set your database columns */
TERMINATED BY '\n' /* Set your line terminations */
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' /* Set what each field is enclosed with */
IGNORE 1 LINES /* Assuming the first line are the headers */
```

Comment: you answer is helpful though i dont want to use the load data infile. the whole idea was to use the file_gets_content, i will try to solve this using both methods. Could you provide any info with the f_gets?